# I cannot set my Seaborn scatterplot to any style besides a white background, no matter how many times I change sns.set_style()

Tags: python, seaborn

```
sns.scatterplot(x = exit_velocity, y = launch_angle, hue = pitch_type)
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
plt.xlabel('Exit Velocity (mph)')
plt.ylabel('Launch Angle (º)')
plt.title('Launch Angle vs. Exit Velocity on Scoring Plays')
plt.legend(loc = 3)

sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

My code is shown above. I am looking to set the background to darkgrid, but everytime python displays my graph, it is a plain white background.

Comment: Try moving `sns.set_style("darkgrid")` before `sns.scatterplot(.........)` statement

Answer (score 0):

The plot style should be defined before the plot itself. Therefore, moving `sns.set_style()` before `sns.scatterplot`should do the job.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,2)))

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.scatterplot(data=df)
plt.xlabel('Exit Velocity (mph)')
plt.ylabel('Launch Angle (º)')
plt.title('Launch Angle vs. Exit Velocity on Scoring Plays')
plt.legend(loc = 3)

sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]